# Error including file (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')

Tags: php

I just uploaded my project to my server in `var/www` made using `slim framework` the project has a folder structure like:

`include
  -Functions.php
controller
  -weeklysummary.php`(Script I want to run)

`vendor
  -autoload.php`

When I try to call a function in the `Functions.php` script On my local machine the project worked fine but on the server it keeps telling me `

```
 Warning: require(../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/project/include/Functions.php on line 11

 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/innov8alert/include/Functions.php on line 11`
```

This is how `Functions.php` Looks like

```
class Functions {

private $conn;


function __construct() {
    require_once 'Connect.php';
    require '../vendor/autoload.php';
    require '../mailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    $db = new Connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}

function __destruct() {

}
```

I looked up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18119133/8410541) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5364233/8410541) but none seemed to help.

Comment: Did you run `composer install` on the server or did you upload the `vendor`-folder? If not, you need to do either or.

Comment: Either the file `/var/www/html/project/include/vendor/autoload.php` doesn't exist or the directory/file has the wrong permissions.

Comment: You could also use defines like: `define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));` So you can change the entire url to something like this: `BASE_PATH _ . '/include/vendor/autoload.php'`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just uploaded, even the local project I have I never used composer, i just copied and pasted slim and it worked.

Comment: @bassxzero it has to be in `html`? its in `www` this is my first time uploading a project to a real server

Comment: Have you tried changing `/` to `\ `? Maybe that helps?

Comment: @RonnieOosting worth taking not, let me try this, is the ` _ ` needed or an error?

Comment: @SourceOverflow won't that mean in the current directory? `..` tells php to look in the directory before the current one which is where my file is

Comment: My comment had a markdown-formating error, sorry. I fixed it

Comment: To use the defined path I suggest to create `defines.php` and create `define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));`. Include this file on top of your page. Then `echo BASE_PATH`; and see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your *current working directory* (CWD), which matches the one where you've started the script from. If this is a website, it should be safe to assume that CWD is where the index.php file is located.

There's 2 ways around the issue:

1) As suggested in the comments, declare a `BASEPATH` constant from inside index.php and always use it to prefix include paths:

```
// index.php:
define('BASEPATH', __DIR__.'/');

// other files:
// require BASEPATH.'path/relative/to/index.php/directory
```

2) Use the `__DIR__` [magic constant](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) itself to prefix includes on files, but relative to where you include them from (this will immediately work in your case without other changes):

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```